# How do I use format() in re.compile

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I want to write a regex that orders python to return items in a list that have sequence of vowels, defined by `len=2`.

```
>>> chars = "aeiou"
>>> len = 2
>>> regex = re.compile(r"[+{}+]{{len}}",format(chars))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 234, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
>>> 
>>> def funct(regex,list):
...     for item in list:
...         if regex.search(item):
...             print(item)
... 
>>> list = ['avid','Chaos','st','Cy']
>>> 
>>> funct(regex,list)
avid
Chaos
```

I should be only getting `Chaos`, not `avid`. I'm having trouble understanding inputting `len` parameter into the `re.compile` module.

Comment: Why are there plusses around your character class?

Comment: Because I want to capture any 2 sequences. I also tried taking them out but I get the same result.

Comment: The plusses in a character class match literal plus characters. Having them twice is redundant, and having them at all contradicts what you say you want.

Comment: regex = re.compile(r"[{}]{{len}}",format(chars)) but this returns the same result avid, Chaos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misuse of formatting has nothing to do with regular expressions. It appears that on top of everything else, you are incorrectly trying to use an f-string along with formatting. Among other things, you need to prefix an f-string with `f` and you can invoke methods with a period, not a comma.

The two formatting operations are interchangeable, and have a clearly defined evaluation order (f-string, then format method). However, it is generally better to use one or the other, not both. Things get unnecessarily complicated otherwise.

Using f-strings:

```
regex = re.compile(f"[{chars}]{{{len}}}")
```

Double braces are interpreted as literal braces in format strings. You need another, third set, to indicate that `len` is a formatted expression.

Using format:

```
regex = re.compile("[{}]{{{}}}".format(chars, len))
regex = re.compile("[{chars}]{{{len}}}".format(chars= chars, len=len))
regex = re.compile("[{0}]{{{len}}}".format(chars, len=len))
```

Using both (for completeness):

```
regex = re.compile(f"[{{}}]{{{{{len}}}}}".format(chars))
```

In no case do you need `+` inside your character class. In square brackets, `+` is matched against literal plus character. It does not act as some magical quantifier. Also, repeating characters in a character class is pointlessly redundant.

Since your string does not have any backslashes in it, it doesn't need to be a raw string, and doesn't need the `r` prefix.

Comment: No, I'm trying to learn how to use parameters in regex. But thank you for the comment.

Comment: I realized what I missed was that I was supposed to do three brackets, not two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an f-string by adding an `f` before the quotes of the string literal so that you can use one pair of curly brackets around `len` to evaluate its value as part of the string, and use a `.` (rather than a `,`) to invoke the `format` method of the string. But since the f-string is evaluated first before being passed to `str.format` for formatting, in order for the empty curly brackets `{}` to be preserved literally by the f-string parser you would have to use double curly brackets to escape them. But then since you need curly brackets around the value of `len` in order for it to be a quantifier in your regex, you need to escape them once again by doubling them for `str.format` to preserve the curly brackets:

```
regex = re.compile(fr"[+{{}}+]{{{{{len}}}}}".format(chars))
```

Since curly brackets have special meanings in all of f-strings, `str.format` and regex, I would suggest that you format your string with a string formatting operator `%` instead so you don't have to deal with the escape hell above:

```
regex = re.compile(r'[+%s+]{%d}' % (chars, len))
```

Comment: Hi, I get the message SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed, and still get avid as result?

Comment: Why would you use both an f-string and format in the first place?

Comment: @song0089 It does return a regex, which is then stored in your `regex` variable. You just need to use `regex` in a search.

Comment: I did, using the function above funct(regex,list)

Comment: @song0089 I see. You need to escape the curly brackets again so that you can use the curly brackets as quantifier in the regex. I've updated the answer accordingly.