# RegEx pattern written as f-string returns different result than a raw string one

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to match this:

```py
text = "111111"
reps = 2

f_pattern = re.compile(rf"(\w)(?=\1{{reps}})")
f_matches = re.findall(f_pattern, text)
## returns: []

r_pattern = re.compile(r"(\w)(?=\1{2})")
r_matches = re.findall(r_pattern, text)
## returns: ['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

How should the f-string pattern be written to return non-empty result?

Comment: This is just a typo and a very-well known issue (already collected 1727 upvotes!): `{reps}` is a variable expanded in the f-string, and you need `{{` to define a literal `{` and `}}` to define a literal `}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `rf"(\w)(?=\1{{{reps}}})")` instead of `rf"(\w)(?=\1{{reps}})")`.

`{{` is a way to escape single `{` inside any f-string, same for `}`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1NCoMwEAXg/ZwiZJVAKWjX0osIRewEA/ljHGhFPHsaLYQu7OwevDdfWniK4Zaz9SkSC0IAxjeLTsjmOAmEaS65BTCPNDAjhRIJr2P0yTpUZKTqX1rdu75Z13Xvb9umpS4DP/A44fwdGBueg3Oq/rmIHdOQyAZWta0B6A/1I7UHQecEnRO1rXP@AA)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this answer:

[How do I use format() in re.compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980108/how-do-i-use-format-in-re-compile)

> Double braces are interpreted as literal braces in format strings. You need another, third set, to indicate that len is a formatted expression.

If you use double brace, f-string thinks its a literal brace and skips it. use 3 braces so 2 of the braces will be considered as a literal brace and another set for format string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the curly bracket for literal print. so here is the solution

```
text = "111111"
reps = 2
 
f_pattern = re.compile(rf"(\w)(?=\1{{ {reps} }})")
f_matches = re.findall(f_pattern, text)
```